# Geometry contains non-closed polygon: GeoServer output from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I have imported a shp file using PostGIS shapefile loader plugin for pgAdmin3. The geometry type of the table created is MultiPolygon. I have cross checked the same using the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE GeometryType(the_geom)<>'MULTIPOLYGON';
```

The output is 0 here. But when I uploaded this table in GeoServer, in layer preview the output is showing

> ERROR: geometry contains non-closed rings.

I again went back to PostGIS and used the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE isClosed(the_geom) = FALSE;
```

Surprisingly the output is 0 again. Can anybody please explain me what is going wrong here? And how can I overcome this error? Thanks in advance.

N.B.: I am using PostgreSQl 8.4.8, PostGIS 1.5.2 and GeoServer 2.1.1

Comment: try a query with ST_IsValidReason: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_IsValidReason.html

Comment: It returns `ERROR:  POSTGIS2GEOS conversion failed. NOTICE:  IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring.` I have tried with **ST_IsValid** function. It returns a few records, but can't understand what the problem is?